# How to run node module in php and display output?

Tags: php, npm, node-modules

I have a use case where i need to run a node module in php script and display it's output back on the page. Here's the steps I followed:

1. I have installed the  module `npm install -g md2gslides`
2. I am using PHP's  `exec()` for running the module 
   `exec('node_modules/md2gslides/bin//md2gslides.js --version 2>&1', $output);`
   But it's not working. The error is below:
   [image]

However, it runs in ubuntu's terminal without issues.
[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: try to use `shell_exec` instead of `exec`

Comment: Thanks but still the same error.

Comment: try to add the absolute `path` it may be the problem

Comment: whatever i use whether exec(),shell_exec(),system().. it's the same error. I think it has to do with the nodejs. any thoughts?

Comment: really I don't know

Comment: i found something would help here if you just want to get the version inside a php script
you could use this command instead `npm -v md2gslides` inside of `exec` it works for me

Comment: Thanks @Joseph The error is because of the path.join() in the md2gslides.js file. I modified the file and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error not because of php but because of the `path.join()` in line 33 of md2gslides.js 
`const STORED_CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(USER_HOME, '.md2googleslides', 'credentials.json');`

It tries to find the credentials.json in users home directory. But I think it's unable to.

So I moved the file to `node_modules/md2gslides/bin` and modified `path.join()` as 
 `path.join(__dirname, '.md2googleslides', 'credentials.json')`

This solved the issue.